# How to get only rows <= (Quantity) Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi I recently wanted to have a report where we can see only the rows that are less or equal than a quantity

example

I have this table

```
USER   QUANTITY
JOHN       2        
JOHN       3        
JOHN       1         
JOHN       3
```

and I want to show only the rows where the Total is 5

and it should show

```
USER    QUANTITY    
JOHN       2        
JOHN       3
```

I never tried this kind of query and I dont know where to start

Can you help me?

Comment: So you pick two rows that add up to 5? And if there are six rows with values 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, then which rows would you pick and why?

Comment: And what if there are four rows with the values 2, 2, 2, 2? Then there is no way to get to five. What would you do then?

Comment: OP you need to explain further if you want our help

Comment: In case you have 1,1,1,2,2,3  you will show 1,1,1,2 only  and in case you will have 2,2,2,2 you will have 2,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your requirements, but hopefully this can get you started:

Schema

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #YourTable 
CREATE TABLE #YourTable ([USER] VARCHAR(50), QUANTITY INT);
INSERT #YourTable ([USER], QUANTITY) 
VALUES ('JOHN', 2)
    ,('JOHN', 3)
    ,('JOHN', 1)
    ,('JOHN', 1)
    ,('JOHN', 2)
    ,('MICHAEL', 2)
    ,('MICHAEL', 2)
    ,('MICHAEL', 2)
    ,('MICHAEL', 2)
```

Query

```
DECLARE @Limit INT = 5

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [USER], QUANTITY
        , RunningTotal = SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY [USER] ORDER BY [USER] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM #YourTable
)
SELECT [USER], QUANTITY FROM cte 
    WHERE RunningTotal <= @Limit
```

Result

```
+---------+----------+
|  USER   | QUANTITY |
+---------+----------+
| JOHN    |        2 |
| JOHN    |        3 |
| MICHAEL |        2 |
| MICHAEL |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for. As an extra how do I get 2,2,1  from 2,2,2,2